# I need assistance with classes

Tags: python

Getting this error:

```
my_new_car = car('audi' , 'a4' , 2016)
TypeError: car() takes no arguments
```

My code:

```
class car:
    def ___init___(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year    
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

my_new_car = car('audi' , 'a4' , 2016)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
```

Comment: You did put 3 `_` in init. You only need two `_` before and after init. `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

- You did put 3 _ in init. You only need two _ before and after init. `__init__`

```
class car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year    
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

my_new_car = car('audi' , 'a4' , 2016)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` function has too many underscores.  You should have 2 on each side, but you have 3.